AWS - Client VPN Endpoint hostname is not resolvable
I created a Client-VPN-Endpoint in AWS and I'm trying to connect using AWS VPN client but I get the error "Connection failed. Try again."
I tried to nslookup or ping endpoint but I see that it can't be resolved.
C:\Users>ping cvpn-endpoint-123456.prod.clientvpn.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Ping request could not find host cvpn-endpoint-123456.prod.clientvpn.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com. Please check the name and try again.

Should I wait for a while for the lookup to work or am I missing something?

The domain name should be public and resolve quickly - few mins at most I would expect. See if it can resolve during an online lookup - I tend to use mxtoolbox looking for A / CNAME records.

It seems I had to append a random string as a prefix for the endpoint URL and then it resolves according to this and this documentation.

Open the Client VPN endpoint configuration file using your preferred
text editor. Locate the line that specifies the Client VPN endpoint
DNS name, and prepend a random string to it so that the format is
random_string.displayed_DNS_name. For example:
Original DNS name:
cvpn-endpoint-0102bc4c2eEXAMPLE.clientvpn.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
Modified DNS name:
asdfa.cvpn-endpoint-0102bc4c2eEXAMPLE.clientvpn.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Without random prefix it doesn't resolve.
C:\Users>ping cvpn-endpoint-123456.prod.clientvpn.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Ping request could not find host cvpn-endpoint-123456.prod.clientvpn.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com. Please check the name and try again.

Prefixing it with "testing" and it resolves to 18.153.138.230
C:\Users>ping testing.cvpn-endpoint-123456.prod.clientvpn.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com


Pinging testing.cvpn-endpoint-123456.prod.clientvpn.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com [18.153.138.230] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 18.153.138.230:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)

